Why does it take so long to execute git fetch for the second time?
My project repository is very large, developed over 6 years, and has 3~4G of git history. If it takes a long time to pull the code for the first time, I can understand.
Recently, I encountered a problem. When I executed the following command for the first time, it was completed very quickly. But when I executed it for the second time in a short time, it took a lot of time
My command:
git fetch --no-tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- git@code.wexx.com:ipc/hj_app.git "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"

The first time console:
xxx@xxxMac-mini hj_app % git fetch --no-tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- git@code.woxx.com:ipc/hj_app.git "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
remote: Enumerating objects: 56, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (56/56), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 4), reused 2 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), 609 bytes | 304.00 KiB/s, done.
From code.wexx.com:ipc/hj_app
 * [new branch]              dev-ignoreAnyway-20240911-test1 -> origin/dev-ignoreAnyway-20240911-test1

The second time consle:
xxx@xxxMac-mini hj_app % git fetch --no-tags --force --progress --depth=1 -- git@code.woxx.com:ipc/hj_app.git "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
remote: Enumerating objects: 287000, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (241941/241941), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (123158/123158), done.
Receiving objects:  36% (84098/231341), 23.28 MiB | 3.33 MiB/s

After the first git fetch is completed, if there are no new changes on the git server, the second git fetch will have problems. If there are new branches or tags on the git server, the second git fetch will be very fast.
After the download is complete, I found a file added to .git/objects/pack, which is about 3.1G. It seems that the long download is for this file. But why is it downloaded? How can I avoid downloading it?
update: git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
To add some background, I first encountered this problem in CI/CD (Jenkins). And I can reproduce this problem in my local environment

First time: "remote: Enumerating objects: 56, done.". Second time: "remote: Enumerating objects: 287000, done.". Now, why that is the case, I don't immediately see. It's as iff the --depth option is ignored.

maybe the * in "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" only yielded one result (master branch) the first time and way more branches in the second run? Does it also take as long without that part?

@dan1st Thanks your reply. I need to map all remote refs to local, so the * cannot be removed.

note that depth=1 can yield counter intuitive results: since you don't have the complete history locally, the server may not be able to compare the fine grained content of your repo and respond with the complete content of the new commits

What is the context of your actions ? for example: is this a persistent clone you work on ? or a repo used in CI/CD ?

@LeGEC This problem was encountered in CI/CD (Jenkins). And my local environment can also reproduce this problem

The server is different in both commands, is that a typo? code.woxx.com != code.weoa.com. If not maybe they have a different set of branches?

@rodrigo I have edited question's body

You have truncated the output of the second fetch, but it shows many, many more objects being fetched. There might not be any newly-created history upstream when you run the second fetch, but there's newly-referenced history matching the tips you asked it to look at. What exactly that history is, Git told you in the parts of the fetch output you didn't include in your question, just like it told you the one branch tip it fetched in the first.
If you want to preflight a fetch, to see what refs it's going to update, add --dry-run to the options.
